# Sort objects highest-lowest in Java with ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, methods

Write a method to return the Toy that occurs in the list most frequent and another method to sort the toys by count.

This is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToyStore {
    private ArrayList<Toy> toyList;

    public ToyStore() {
    }

    public void loadToys(String toys) {
        toyList = new ArrayList<Toy>();
        for (String item : toys.split(" ")) {
            Toy t = getThatToy(item);
            if (t == null) {
                toyList.add(new Toy(item));
            } else {
                t.setCount(t.getCount() + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public Toy getThatToy(String nm) {
        for (Toy item : toyList) {
            if (item.getName().equals(nm)) {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getMostFrequentToy() {
        int position = 0;
        int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = toyList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (toyList.get(i).getCount() > maximum)
                maximum = toyList.get(i).getCount();
            position = i;
        }
        return toyList.get(position).getName();
    }

    public void sortToysByCount() {
        ArrayList<Toy> t = new ArrayList<Toy>();
        int count = 0;
        int size = toyList.size();

        for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
            t.add(new Toy(getMostFrequentToy()));
            t.get(count).setCount(getThatToy(getMostFrequentToy()).getCount());
            toyList.remove(getThatToy(getMostFrequentToy()));
            count++;
        }

        toyList = t;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return toyList + "" + "\n" + "max == " + getMostFrequentToy();
    }
}
```

Here is the method I care about

```
public void sortToysByCount() {
    ArrayList<Toy> t = new ArrayList<Toy>();
    int count = 0;
    int size = toyList.size();

    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        t.add(new Toy(getMostFrequentToy()));
        t.get(count).setCount(getThatToy(getMostFrequentToy()).getCount());
        toyList.remove(getThatToy(getMostFrequentToy()));
        count++;
    }

    toyList = t;
}
```

Here is my output

```
  [sorry 4, bat 1, train 2, teddy 2, ball 2]
```

Here is what I want

```
  [sorry 4, train 2, teddy 2, ball 2, bat 1];
```

What is wrong in my code? How do I do it?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and figure it out. Homework is meant to teach through trial and error, what's the point if we do it for you?

Comment: It looks like a homework. Here's our policy [about homeworks](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `getMostFrequentToy()` method:

Replace

```
        if (toyList.get(i).getCount() > maximum)
            maximum = toyList.get(i).getCount();
        position = i;
```

with

```
        if (toyList.get(i).getCount() > maximum) {
            maximum = toyList.get(i).getCount();
            position = i;
        }
```

because you want to get the position that corresponds to that maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You have some in-efficiencies in your code. Every single time you call `getMostFrequentToy()`, you are iterating over the whole list, which may be fine as you are constantly removing objects, but you really don't need to make `new Toy` objects for those that already exist in the list.

So, this is "better", but still not sure you need to `getThatToy` when you should already know which one is the most frequent.

```
String frequent;
for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
    frequent = getMostFrequentToy();
    t.add(new Toy(frequent));
    t.get(count).setCount(getThatToy(frequent).getCount());
    toyList.remove(getThatToy(frequent));
    count++;
}
```

---

Anyways, I think the instructions asked you to return the Toy object, not its name.

It's quite simple, just keep track of the max count.

```
public Toy getMostFrequentToy() {
    Toy mostFrequent = null;
    int maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (Toy t : toyList) {
        if (t.getCount() > maximum)
            mostFrequent = t;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Now, the above code can become

```
public void sortToysByCount() {
    ArrayList<Toy> t = new ArrayList<Toy>();
    // int count = 0;
    int size = toyList.size();

    Toy frequent;
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        frequent = getMostFrequentToy();
        t.add(frequent);
        // t.get(count).setCount(frequent.getCount()); // Not sure about this
        toyList.remove(frequent);
        // count++;
    }

    toyList.clear();
    toyList.addAll(t);
}
```

Realistically, though, when you want to sort, you really should see how to [create a `Comparator` for your `Toy` objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property).